# How do I upsample an irregular dataset based on a data column?

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have a pandas dataframe that contains logged data based on depth. The depth is spaced irregularly. 
I need the dataset to be spaced in regular dx steps.

Is there a way of doing this without stuffing it into separated numpy arrays and interpolating them seperately?

Seperate interpolation of all columns.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0. ,   2. ,   3.5,   5. ,   6. ,  18.], [100,  20, 150,  80, 110, 125], [1.  ,  0.5 ,  2.6 ,  0.01,  3.  ,  2.]]).T, columns=['depth', 'value1', 'value2'])

step=0.05
# this is what the column "depth" should be like afterwards
target_depth=np.linspace(df['a'].min(),df['a'].max(),int(df['a'].max()/step))
```

A pandas or other library function that does the interpolation/resampling

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with `interp1d` from the `signal` package.